# How to receive a request from browser to .NET 4.5 C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, extjs

I have inherited some code at work which seems unable to get more than the first parameter.  If I try to add a JSON object, it does not seem to get across.  The front end is written in Ext.js and the back end is C# .NET 4.5.

Browser code:

```
        frame.onload = WorkManager.util.DownloadPrint.Unmask();         
        var form = Ext.get('iframeForm');
        if (form == null) {
            form = body.createChild({
                tag: 'form',
                cls: 'x-hidden',
                id: 'iframeForm',
                name: 'iframeForm',
                standardSubmit: true,
                method: 'POST',
                //action: webroot + 'dispatch.aspx',
                action: AppSettings.root + '/Download/GetExcelData/' + reqType,
                params: {'startDate': 'test', 'endDate':'anothertest'},
                target: 'downloadIframe'
            });
```

And back end code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Fcx.Fu.Tast.DBAccess.E2EUI;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Fcx.Fu.Tast.Xtra.WebApi.Controllers.E2Z
{
//public class Dates { string startDate{get; set;} string endDate{get;         set;}}
public class DownloadController : XtraBaseController
{

    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetExcelData(String id, JObject data)
    {


        switch (id)
        {
            case "xeDownload":
                return GetExceptionData(id);

            case "xaeDownload":
                return GetAssetExceptionData(id);

            case "oobDownload":
                return GetOOBExceptionData(id);

            case "techShortDownload":
                return GetTechShortExceptionData(id);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

The "id" comes in correctly, but the Json data parameter in the HttpResponseMessage comes in empty...

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you can look at the Network tab and view the request headers and see if it matches what your API end point expects.

Comment: Try making a POST request to the endpoint yourself using something like fiddler or postman. Then take it from there

Answer (score 0):

Send the data parameter as json. You are currently sending endDate which does not map to a parameter of your method.

```
params: {'startDate': 'test', data: { 'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2', 'property3': { 'p3property1': 'p3value1' } },
```